# Trouble with permissions with source exposed via NFS to VM

Tags: nfs, webstorm

I'm having a bit of trouble with permissions with this approach:

I have a massive code base that is designed to be run on a local Virtual machine.

Since I am using webstorm it is helpful to have the source locally. When the source is local I expose the files (chmod -R 777 /exposedDir ) via NFS to my VM.

However the vm is having some permissions issues..

Is this a good approach, is there anything else I can do to ensure not permissions issues?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the permissions problems you're seeing?

Comment: a general note not related to NFS: WebStorm overwrites original files permissions on save in some cases; you need to turn 'Use "safe write"' option (settings/general) off to work out the problem